# How to use server variables in PHPUnit Test cases?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I am testing modules using PHPUnit Test cases. All the things working fine but when i use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` it gives fatal error and stops execution.

**CategoryControllerTest.php**

```
<?php
namespace ProductBundle\Controller\Tests\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
class CategoryControllerTest extends WebTestCase {

     protected function setUp() {
        static::$kernel = static::createKernel();
        static::$kernel->boot();
        $this->container = static::$kernel->getContainer();
        $this->em = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    }

    public function testCategory() {
        $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $client = static::createClient(
          array(), array('HTTP_HOST' => static::$kernel->getContainer()->getParameter('test_http_host')
        ));

        $crawler = $client->request('POST', '/category/new');
        $client->enableProfiler();

        $this->assertEquals('ProductBundle\Controller\CategoryController::addAction', $client->getRequest()->attributes->get('_controller'));
        $form = $crawler->selectButton('new_category')->form();
        $form['category[name]'] = "Electronics";
        $form['category[id]']   = "For US";
        $form['category[ip]']   = $ip_address;
        $client->submit($form);

        $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isRedirect('/category/new')); // check if redirecting properly
        $client->followRedirect();
        $this->assertEquals(1, $crawler->filter('html:contains("Category Created Successfully.")')->count());
    }
}
```

**Error**

There was 1 error:

> 1) ProductBundle\Tests\Controller\CategoryControllerTest::testCategory
>   Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR

I have tried to add it in `setUp()` function but it's not working as well.

Comment: You shouldn't directly access `$_SERVER` or other superglobals if you want to make your application more testable. Create containers for them and then mock them when testing.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you haven't sent a request to your application yet, so there is no remote address to refer to. That in fact is what your error is telling us too.

To work around this:

1. move the line to be below:

   ```
   // Won't work, see comment below    
   $crawler = $client->request('POST', '/category/new');
   ```
2. Or you could make up an IP address and test with that. Since you're only using the IP to save a model, that will work just as well.

Like @apokryfos mentioned in the comments, it's considered bad practice to access superglobals in test cases. So option 2 is probably your best choice here.

Comment: You can not use `REMOTE_ADDR` even after moving line to below line `$crawler = $client->request('POST', '/category/new');`.

Comment: Really? Anyway, then you should really use option 2, which is the better choice no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

Create service which returns ip address and mock the service in test case.

Here, create controller and service as **UserIpAddress**. `get()` will return ip address of user.

**service.yml**

```
UserIpAddress:
    class: AppBundle\Controller\UserIpAddressController
    arguments: 
    container: "@service_container"
```

**UserIpAddressController.php**

```
class UserIpAddressController
{
  public function get()
  {
    return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  }
}
```

> Create mock of "UserIpAddress" service. It will override existing service. Use 'UserIpAddress' service to get ip address in your project.

**CategoryControllerTest.php**

```
$UserIpAddress = $this->getMockBuilder('UserIpAddress')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();

$UserIpAddress->expects($this->once())
  ->method('get')
  ->willReturn('192.161.1.1'); // Set ip address whatever you want to use
```

Now, get ip address using `$UserIpAddress->get();`

Answer (score 0):

You can either create another class that will return the server var then mock it.

Or you can set/unset the server var directly into your test case.
Did it with PHPUnit 6.2.2 :

```
 /**
 * Return true if the user agent matches a robot agent
 */
public function testShouldReturnTrueIfRobot()
{
    $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)';

    $this->configMock->method('getRobotUserAgents')
        ->willReturn('bot|crawl|slurp|spider|mediapartner');

    $test = $this->robotTest->isBot();

    static::assertTrue($test);
}

/**
 * Test return false if no user agent
 */
public function testShouldReturnFalseIfNoAgentUser()
{
    unset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

    $test = $this->robotTest->isBot();

    static::assertFalse($test);
}
```

Where tested method is :

```
 /**
 * Detect if current user agent matches a robot user agent
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isBot(): bool
{
    if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
        return false;
    }

    $userAgents = $this->config->getRobotUserAgents();
    $pattern = '/' . $userAgents . '/i';

    return \preg_match($pattern, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
}
```

Comment: Make sure to unset any changes after the test, as the changes will persist in other changes and may give you troubles.