# Symfony 2.8 functional testing: access to local file not found

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, symfony-2.8

I'm coding a functional test that calls a route whose controller has to read on local file system a specific file. The code in my controller is:

```
$document_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$patch = $document_root . "/../app/config/tabelle/config.json";
if (file_exists($patch)) { ... }else{ die; }
```

The problem is that when I run the controller visiting by myself the URL and loading the page on my browser, everything works properly.
But when I run my functional test, that is supposed to load exactly the same URL I visited manually by browser, the test fails because controller cannot find the file.
Maybe I have to configure phpunit in a way that tells him which root folder he has to consider?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate may be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491437/pass-variable-to-phpunit

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588862/how-to-use-server-variables-in-phpunit-test-cases

Answer (score 0):

I solved adopting the Symfony2 native way to get the ROOT_DIR. Rather than using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] I used: $document_root = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir');