# How to get PHPUnit testing working with a function that returns an IP?

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm, tdd

I'm just new to TDD and I've installed PHPUnit with PhpStorm.

I have this class and function, and I want to test for the IP address match.

```
class ip_request
{

    function getRealIpAddr()
    {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
        {
            $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
        elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
        {
            $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
        else
        {
            $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        return $ip;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create the code for the test, and I'm not sure what to put in.

I have tried

```
public function testGetRealIpAddr()
    {
        
        $expected = '127.0.0.1';
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $test);
    }
```

But `$test` is undefined obviously.

What should I do next?

Tried suggestion given

```
public function testGetRealIpAddr()
    {
        $UserIpAddress = $this
            ->getMockBuilder('ip_request')
            ->getMock();

        $UserIpAddress->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getRealIpAddr')
            ->willReturn('127.0.0.1'); // Set ip address whatever you want to use
    }
```

But the error I get now is that

```
Trying to configure method "getRealIpAddr()" which cannot be configured because it does not exist, has not been specified, is final, or is static
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use server variables in PHPUnit Test cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588862/how-to-use-server-variables-in-phpunit-test-cases)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this similarly to how @hakre suggested,

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?? '127.0.0.1';
```

I added `?? '127.0.0.1'` to the end of that statement, and that fixed it.

Also just updated my test function to show only

```
 $local = new ip_request();
 $this->assertEquals('127.0.0.1', $local->getRealIpAddr());
```

Answer (score 1):

The method / function you want to test has a *hidden dependency*: `$_SERVER`.

Spotting this can also lead to a solution making the code more modular and easier testable.

This works by exposing the previous hidden dependency with an optional parameter:

```
function getRealIpAddr(array $server = null)
{
    $server ??= $_SERVER;
    
    if (!empty($server['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
        $ip = $server['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($server['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
        $ip = $server['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $server['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    return $ip;
}
```

In the unit test you then test the function result based on the input.

A unit test however can not highlight the massive security issues that function has, which is likely out of scope for your question, so I only leave a remark.

Comment: Thanks I did solve this, but I appreciate you showing me this method, thanks.